# Using STDIN from pipe in sed command to replace value in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I've got a command to perform a series of commands that produce a variable output string such as `123456`.  I want to pipe that to a `sed` command replacing a known string in a csv file that looks like this:
`Fred,Wilma,Betty,Barney`

However, the command below does not work and I haven't found any other references to using pipe values as the variable for a replace.

How does this code change if the values in the csv are in a random order and I always want to change the second value?

Example code:

```
find / -iname awk 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -c1-10 > test.txt | 
sed -i -e '/Wilma/ r test.txt' -e 's/Wilma//' input.csv
```

Contents of input.csv should become: `Fred,0d522cd316,Betty,Barney`

Comment: Can you give an example line from input.csv?

Comment: You have your pipes and redirections a bit mixed up. Looking at the input.csv and the desired output one might better understand what you are trying to do and trying to achieve.

Comment: I think you could abuse cats. `sed -i -e 's/Wilma/'"$(cat)"'/' input.csv`. What is the output of `find / -iname awk 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -c1-10`?

Comment: Is the CSV file always just one line long?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, in

```sh
find / -iname awk 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -c1-10 > test.txt | sed -i -e '/Wilma/ r test.txt' -e 's/Wilma//' input.csv
```

you have a bug. That "> test.txt" after cut is going to eat your stdin on sed, so things go weird with that pipe afterwards taking stdin. You don't want a pipe there, or you don't want to redirect to a file.

The way to take piped stdin and use it as a parameter in a command is through `xargs`.

```sh
find / -iname awk 2>/dev/null | sha256sum | cut -c1-10 | xargs --replace=INSERTED -- sed -i -e 's/Wilma/INSERTED/' input.csv
```

(...though that find|shasum is suspect too, in that the order of files is random(ish) and it matters for a reliable sum. You prpobably mean to "|sort" after find.)

(Some would `sed -i -e "s/Wilma/$(find|sort|shasum|cut)" f`, but I ain't among them. Animals.)

Answer (score 3):

1. For replacing a fixed string like *"Wilma"*, try:

   ```
   sed -i 's/Wilma/'"$(find / -iname awk 2>/dev/null | 
                       sha256sum | cut -c1-10)"'/' input.csv
   ```
2. To replace the 2nd field no matter what's in it, try:

   ```
   sed -i 's/[^,]*/'"$(find / -iname awk 2>/dev/null | 
                       sha256sum | cut -c1-10)"'/2' input.csv
   ```

Comment: Animal style, yeah!